# Power Query Table pivot transformation

Tags: powerquery

Find the attached image, I want to transform the days to date and put all days in a column[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS6KG.png)

Comment: import the data to powerquery per day and append all days there.... or use powerpivot...

Answer (score 0):

In powerquery, try this to re-arrange the column. You have not provided any information needed to figure out how to insert the date

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
base=1, group=25, // 1 base column, then groups of 25, stack them
Combo = List.Transform(List.Split(List.Skip(Table.ColumnNames(Source),base),group), each List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),base) & _),
#"Added Custom" =List.Accumulate(Combo,#table({"Column1"}, {}),(state,current)=> state & Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(Source, current)),1)),
#"Rename"=Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Custom",List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(#"Added Custom"),List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),base+group)}))
in #"Rename"
```